# Improper reading of file in C

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I am doing a socket programming for hospital chanelling.
I am trying to read a text file like this

```
1   Kavi    card    0   0   0
2   Anparasanesan   gene    0   0   0
3   Thilak  card    0   0   0
4   Akilanesan  immu    0   0   0
5   Aravinthanesan  derm    0   0   0
6   Akalya  derm    0   0   0
7   Vishvapriya derm    0   0   0
8   Kavinga immu    0   0   0
9   Anjalie andr    0   0   0
10  Tom andr    0   0   0
```

but when i am reading that file it gives me the output as :

[image]

```
1   Kavi    cardgenecardimmudermdermdermimmuandrandr
2   Anparasanesan   genecardimmudermdermdermimmuandrandr
3   Thilak  cardimmudermdermdermimmuandrandr
4   Akilanesan  immudermdermdermimmuandrandr
5   Aravinthanesan  dermdermdermimmuandrandr
6   Akalya  dermdermimmuandrandr
7   Vishvapriya dermimmuandrandr
8   Kavinga immuandrandr
9   Anjalie andrandr
10  Tom andr
```

Here is my code segment

```
char line[MAXCHAR];
        int x = 0;
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){ 
            sscanf(line,"%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d",&dno,&dname,&dspl,&ti1,&ti2,&ti3);

            id[x]=dno;
            strncpy(name[x], dname, 50);
            strncpy(spl[x], dspl, 4);
            times[x][0]=ti1;
            times[x][1]=ti2;
            times[x][2]=ti3;

            x++;
            }

        int z=0;
        for(z=0;z<10;z++)
        {
            snprintf(line, sizeof(line),"%d\t%s\t%s\n",id[z],name[z],spl[z]);
            n = strlen(line);
            Writen(sockfd,line,n);
        }
```

Comment: You need to show the declarations for the variables you use, plus the `Writen` function and the initialization of `sockfd`.

Comment: very first thing, learn to use your debugger to step through your code and look at all the variables.

Comment: @CareyGregory here you don't need those things since those things are coming under socket functions those things are working fine only the file reading part it self having some issues. Here the code segment that have put above is enough. So kindly help me with the above file reading part issues

Comment: I cannot see the output. Please post text as text. Please do not post screen shots or it.

Comment: @pm100 here i have came to the above conclusion by doing several debugging after that only i have raised the above question. Thank you for your Consideration.

Comment: @alk check it now i have added it. Thank you.

Comment: "*here you don't need those things*" Unfortunately we do, context mostly always is important.

Comment: @alk will consider that in future

Comment: How `spl` is declared? If it is `char spl[10][4]`, there would be no terminating zeroes, leading to the behavior you observe.

Comment: `here you don't need those things` -- That response just earned you a close vote.

Answer (score 2):

Let us look at one of the problems.

**evil `strncpy`**

Code is using `strncpy` with a   [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) 4.  This does not insure `spl[x]` is a *string* as the characters may lack a final *null character*.

```
        strncpy(spl[x], dspl, 4);  // Avoid code like this
```

Later code tries to print a *string* with `"%s"` and `spl[z]` and gets "cardgene..." rather than the expected "card".  When `spl[z]` is not a string, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB) - anything may happen.

```
        // Alternative: could limit output with
        snprintf(line, sizeof(line),"%.*s\n",(int) (sizeof spl[z]), spl[z]);
```

---

**How to fix?**

Do not use `sscanf(line,"%s",&dspl);` as it lacks either a width limit, or it is not known that `dspl` is about the same size of `line`.  I'd expect

```
char dspl[4+1];
sscanf(line,"%4s", dspl);
```

Better to insure the source string and destination array are sufficient than use `strncpy()` without tests.

```
char spl[X_N][4+1];
char dspl[sizeof spl[0]];

// strncpy(spl[x], dspl, 4);
strcpy(spl[x], dspl);
```

Others fixes include make certain the `sscanf()` completed as expected. A simple approach uses `" %n"` to record the scan offset, if it got that far and then look for extra garbage.  Unnecessary `"\t"` removed.

```
// Insure  dname is at least 50+1, dspl is 4+1 or as big as the line
char dname[sizeof line];
char dspl[sizeof line];

// sscanf(line,"%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d",&dno,&dname,&dspl,&ti1,&ti2,&ti3);
int n = 0;
sscanf(line,"%d%50s%4s%d%d%d %n",&dno,dname,dspl,&ti1,&ti2,&ti3, &n);
if (n==0 || line[n]) {
  puts("Bad Input");  // Handle bad input in some fashion
  exit(RETURN_FAILURE);
}
```